# My Sites Link not appearing

Tags: sharepoint-server, my-site, configuration

This is SharePoint 2010 environment. I am trying to configure My Sites in a test environment, I have the User Profile successfully running and have created My sites web application and site collection created. I have enabled the Self service site creation and configured everything in User Profile service as well.

What is strange is after all the configuration "My site" link doesn't appear in the drop down. My questions is at what stage the "My site" link will appear in the drop down.